# JSESSIONID missing when /xforms-server POST sent by orbeon client side ajax caller

Tags: orbeon

We are coping with orbeon session management:

We have a custom authentication mechanism that works fine on the server (locally), but we got 403 at every /xforms-server call after login when we are trying to use orbeon remotely.

Our custom authentication happens at tomcat/container level, and the result is a standard JSESSIONID cookie that present in the response of the login request.

The "funny" thing is that this JSESSIONID is present at every "normal" browser request (for resources) except these, so those that are trying to reach the /xforms-server

As if the client side javascript would not set this JSESSIONID cookie for the xhr request.

- We already set the cookie forwarding described [here](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/general/properties-general-http-client#cookies-forwarding)
- We already set the cookie path descibed [here](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/session)

We already raise the log4j level and orbeon debug but we got only the same info that we have already known, that the sessionId cookie was not forwarded to the server.

Do you have any idea what else we could do?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that the `JSESSIONID` cookie is not sent by the browser for Ajax requests. The cookie isn't set by JavaScript. It is set by the server with a `Set-Cookie` header. For instance, with Orbeon Forms deployed on `/démo`, if you clear your cookies, the first time you make a request to the server, in the response you will see:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FAD4923E960D0C0341BC750265222FB6; Path=/demo; Secure; HttpOnly
```

Note the `Path=/demo`. This is the server telling the browser "don't send the cookie unless it is a request under `/demo`. Could you try clearing your cookies, and checking what the header looks like? Does it include the path used for the Ajax request?

It might go without saying, but I'll say it anyway ;), in addition to the path, you need to make sure that Ajax request go to the same server from which the page was loaded, otherwise you have no change that the browser will send the cookie.

Comment: What I have tried to say that in browser debug, we saw everywhere the JSESSIONID cookie forwarded except the /xforms-server calls and therefore and of course we got 403 due to the missing sessionid. We are trying to collect some network data to share.

Comment: As usual, the error was at our side. We have implemented a custom tomcat authenticationvalve. After a successfull login we let the superclass do what it usually does, but we were not aware that the superclass does not make new session. We created it accidentally by a request.getSession() call (we logged that there is a session in the session or not), and the situation above happened when we changed this to request.getSession(false) which does not create new session. So when we changed this back it started to work again. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @m4gic Excellent, I am glad you found where the problem was. And thank you for the update. -Alex